# ACF Save/Post hook and custom post types issue fires on all post types

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have an a situation where i have 5 or more custom post types, each has a function i run afterwards, using the ACF save post hook e.g.

```
    function acf_add_incident($post_id) {

        global $wpdb;
        global $post; 
        global $post_type;
        global $user_ID;
    
        $values = get_fields( $post_id );
        
            if ($post->post_type != 'incident') {       
            
            $pid = $post_id;    
            $latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=incident&numberposts=1");

            do stuff.....
}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_add_incident');
```

Issue I have is when i use if ($post->post_type != 'incident') it does what i want but if I use if ($post->post_type == 'incident') it does not run the function also If i exclude the

```
            $pid = $post_id;    
            $latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=incident&numberposts=1");
```

then it does not get the post id !!! Issue gets worse as it seems not to target the post type im updating but fires for the other post types as well !!! so If i create an incident it runs the functions on the other custom post types too e.g. sites or alerts

Comment: Maybe just use `get_post_type($post_id) != 'incident'` instead